# How to open black Console(Output) Window in windows form application in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, output-window

I can't find how to open that black window that I can cout and stuff. I would appreciate if anybody could help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Default key mapping is Ctrl + W,O

Or do View menu -> Output window

There is also an immediate window which let's you execute statements, like `?myVal` and it will tell you the value.  It can be found at Ctrl+D,I or Debug->Windows->Immediate

Answer (score 3):

That's a [console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) window`, and you open it with [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). See all of the [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But could you please be a little bit more helpful? Should I just call AllocConsole() and it is going to create the black screen and the output when I cout? Because if so, it doesnt work or I do it wrong. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not hesitate, install on your Visual Studio the [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) extension. You can see how easy is to open a new cmd console on the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since it is not answered:
For Visual Studio 2017 under menu
Tools->Nuget Package Magager->Package Manager Console