# How can I keep a console error open in VS when I'm using freeglut and OpenGL?

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, freeglut

I'm trying out a first-time application using freeglut and OpenGL on VS 2015. I'm able to build with no errors. But when I Ctrl+F5 to Start Without Debugging, some error appears on the console, and then the console closes. How can I keep this console window open so I can read the error?

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c), I tried using `std::cin.get` and a breakpoint at the end of my main function, but the console still closes. I can sort of see that the error has some text like "Unable to create OpenGl 4.3 context".

I found that `glutInitContextVersion(4,3)` was the problem (my OpenGL version is only 4.0). I'm still wondering if it's possible to keep the window open when a function raises an error like this.

Here's the main function of the sample app if it helps:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("square.cpp");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    setup();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902200/how-to-open-black-consoleoutput-window-in-windows-form-application-in-visual-s

Comment: @Ripi2 Putting `AllocConsole()` in the start of `main()` didn't work. And output window doesn't have the error messages, only the build status. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the second answer in that post?

Comment: @Ripi2 Ya. The output and immediate window are both on the bottom of the VS ui. They're just both blank when I try to Start w/o Debugging. The error I'm trying to look at is only in the black console that disappears after showing the error.